# D3 v6 Brush Chart

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I'm attempting to create a brushable timeline / swim chart. My problem is implementing the brushing. I'm pretty new to d3 and it looks like most of the examples I found are for previous versions of d3 and now things are done differently. Additionally I'd like to remove the @ts-ignore's I've placed throughout the code. Any help would be great!

[image: Chart]

Code I'd like help with:
The brushed function:

```
function brushed({event, selection}:any) {
        if (event.sourceEvent && event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return; // ignore brush-by-zoom
        var s = selection || x2.range();
        x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));
        //contextArea.select(".area").attr("d", area); -- not sure how to recreate boxes
        // @ts-ignore
        contextArea.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
        // @ts-ignore
        svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
            .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
            .translate(-s[0], 0));
    }
```

the zoomed function:

```
function zoomed({event}:any) {
        if (event.sourceEvent && event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return; // ignore zoom-by-brush
        var t = event.transform;
        x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
        // contextArea.select(".area").attr("d", area); -- not sure how to recreate boxes ?
        // @ts-ignore
        contextArea.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
        // @ts-ignore
        contextArea.select(".brush").call(brush.move, x.range().map(t.invertX, t));
    }
```

D3 example I've attempted to follow:
https://bl.ocks.org/bumbeishvili/6c54d3f0e202aa7004a669a768369c5d

Here's the link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-mendel-ng7q1?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 1):

In D3 v6, sourceEvent was removed from event. Basically, they do not automatically forward the event anymore.

A discussion of the issue can be found here:
https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/222

It seems to be possible to rebuild the old functionality, but it's difficult.

The user Fil proposes a simpler and working solution and links to:
https://blockbuilder.org/Fil/076415313a08e76ae60d468e2cb25909
As the link hints that it will be dead in a while, this is a short snippet of the workaround I have been building for my code:

```
var sourceEvent = null;

function brushed(event) {
    if (sourceEvent === "zoom") return; // ignore brush-by-zoom
    sourceEvent = "brush";
    var s = event.selection || x2.range();
    x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));
    focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
    focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
        .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
        .translate(-s[0], 0));
    sourceEvent = null;
}

function zoomed(event) {
    if (sourceEvent === "brush") return; // ignore zoom-by-brush
    sourceEvent = "zoom";
    var t = event.transform;
    x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
    focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
    focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
    context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, x.range().map(t.invertX, t));
    sourceEvent = null;
}
```

My code is based on:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172

I think it is basically the same family of example as yours, so it should be easy to adapt.